# Как проверить, содержится ли два символа?

Tags: c#

В тексте может содержаться две `*`, как мне сделать проверку `.Contains("*")` 2ух звезд

Пример: `2*,3*,4*-*`, нужно узнать, есть ли 2 звезды в тексте

Comment: Ну наверно посчитать их и сделать проверку? Например, `.Count(x => x == '*') == 2`, первое что пришло в голову..

Comment: А как вы собрались через `Contains()` делать `Count()`? Первый возвращает `bool` (`true/false`) если в коллекции есть искомое значение, а второй возвращает `int` (`1 2 3...`), которое равно числу искомых объектов в коллекции и как вы в `bool` собрались искать и что? Если ваша логика такая: `Взять все объекты равные * и потом их посчитать`, то это будет так `"2*,3*,4*-*".Where(x=>x == '*').Count();`, то есть сначала берем, потом считаем, но зачем нам брать, если можем сразу посчитать?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ИМО, это кривой интерфейс .NET: внутри коллекций (списков) должен быть метод `CountOf`, возвращающий кол-во элементов.

Реализация/использование метода.

**LINQ**

```
str.Count(c => c == '*');
```

**Императивчик**

```
public static int CountOf(this string str, char chr) // тут `chr` - '*'
{
    // checks skipped

    var cnt = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        if (str[i] == chr)
            cnt++;

    return cnt;
}
```